# invalid group specification - None of the groups defined by pid are treated

Tags: stata

I'm trying to do the DID model in Stata using the following panel data. However, the `didregress (Y_it) (D_it), group(pid) time(year)` command gives me the following error: `invalid group specification - None of the groups defined by pid is treated`. I also tried `xtdidregress (Y_it) (D_it), group(pid) time(year)` and set `xtset pid year, delta(2)` before. Does anyone know what the cause of this problem is? The dataset looks like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLLoj.png).

Comment: This seems to be a problem with your data rather than a programming issue.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not obviously a programming problem.